# Why does this CSS cause extremely high memory usage?

Tags: html, css, memory-leaks

I have an e-learning site that is causing Safari on iOS6 to freeze up and eventually shutdown.  Turns out memory usage is increasing to the point where Safari cant handle it and just shuts down. I've slowly removed and added code until I isolated the issue to this set of CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0; padding:0; font-family:'Roboto',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:300;
    background:url(../images/bg-repeat.png) repeat-x bottom left;   
    }
*{outline:none;}
a { text-decoration:none; color:inherit;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ font-weight:300;}
ul, ul li{ padding:0;}

#wrapper {  position:relative; display:block; color:#3b3b3b;        }
#contents-holder{  }
#content-area{ vertical-align:middle; color:#193048; margin-left:2%;}
#content-area h1 { font-weight:300; font-size:63px; border-bottom:2px solid #193048;  padding:0; margin-bottom:10px; }
```

Can anyone guide me as to why this set of CSS is causing memory usage to increment until the point where the browser shuts down?

EDIT:  In case its relevant, I am using JWPlayer 6.6 on this page.  However, it doesnt seem that is the cause of the leak so far since commenting out the above CSS results in stable memory usage.

Comment: Guess #1: the image is HUGE. Guess #2, the front is broken. Have you tried swapping them out?

Comment: Guess #3: applying `*{outline:none;}` to absolutely everything

Comment: Guess #4: You have 7.4 trillion anchor tags.

Comment: I dont have more than 10 anchor tags.  bg-repeat.png is under 4k

Comment: Is it possible to narrow down the CSS any further?

Comment: I remember that sometimes _iOS6_ has a hard time dealing with PNG background, so try to save your image as **non-interlaced PNG** _(...and while you're at it, make it at least 10px wide_), but I doubt that it's the cause of the crash...

Comment: Maybe a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net